# How the hashcode is calculated

Tags: dart

When we write:

```
"exampleString".hashCode
```

Is there a genral mathematical way, some algorithm that calculates it or it gets it from somewhere else in Dart laungage?
And is the hashcode of a `String` value still the same in another languages like java, c++...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions, hashcodes are Dart specific, and perhaps even execution-run specific.  To see how the various hashcodes work, see the source code for any given class.

The Fine Manual says:

> A hash code is a single integer which represents the state of the object that affects operator == comparisons.

> All objects have hash codes. The default hash code implemented by Object represents only the identity of the object, the same way as the default operator == implementation only considers objects equal if they are identical (see identityHashCode).

> If operator == is overridden to use the object state instead, the hash code must also be changed to represent that state, otherwise the object cannot be used in hash based data structures like the default Set and Map implementations.

> Hash codes must be the same for objects that are equal to each other according to operator ==. The hash code of an object should only change if the object changes in a way that affects equality. There are no further requirements for the hash codes. They need not be consistent between executions of the same program and there are no distribution guarantees.

> Objects that are not equal are allowed to have the same hash code. It is even technically allowed that all instances have the same hash code, but if clashes happen too often, it may reduce the efficiency of hash-based data structures like HashSet or HashMap.

> If a subclass overrides hashCode, it should override the operator == operator as well to maintain consistency.

That last point is important.  If two objects are considered == by whatever strategy you want, they must also always have the same hashcode.  The inverse is not necessarily true.